# How to use regex to match some patterns but match nothing if url contains certain words (in Javascript)

Tags: regex

An example is:

- Match everything between slashes that contains dash(`-`),
- But don't match the whole url if it contains `/test/`

so for `/abc/abc-def-gh/a-aa.jpg`, it will match `abc-def-gf`(including slashes or not)
but `/abc/test/abc-def-gh/a-aa.jpg`, it will match nothing

Thanks :)

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you don't need regex for this.

Comment: thx. but in my case, I have to use regex to implement.

Answer (score 1):

Although you can probably do it in one regex, it would probably be easier and have better performance to just use two regex's.  Match `\/test\/` and filter those matches, and then `\/.+-.+\/`.